# Open a program with python minimized or hidden

Tags: python, windows

What I'm trying to do is to write a script which would open an application only in process list. Meaning it would be "hidden". I don't even know if its possible in python.

If its not possible, I would settle for even a function that would allow for a program to be opened with python in a minimized state maybe something like this:

```
import subprocess
def startProgram():
    subprocess.Hide(subprocess.Popen('C:\test.exe')) #  I know this is wrong but you get the idea...
startProgram()
```

Someone suggested to use win32com.client but the thing is that the program that i want to launch doesn't have a COM server registered under the name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use win32api and hide your window e.g. using [win32gui.EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can enumerate all top windows and hide your window

Here is a small example, you may do something like this:

```
import subprocess
import win32gui
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe"])
# lets wait a bit to app to start
time.sleep(3)

def enumWindowFunc(hwnd, windowList):
    """ win32gui.EnumWindows() callback """
    text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    className = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    #print hwnd, text, className
    if text.find("Notepad") >= 0:
        windowList.append((hwnd, text, className))

myWindows = []
# enumerate thru all top windows and get windows which are ours
win32gui.EnumWindows(enumWindowFunc, myWindows)

# now hide my windows, we can actually check process info from GetWindowThreadProcessId
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx
for hwnd, text, className in myWindows:
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, False)

# as our notepad is now hidden
# you will have to kill notepad in taskmanager to get past next line
proc.wait()
print "finished."
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the corresponding module on Linux?

Comment: How can I hide / show / minimize / maximise my window based on its process name instead of window title, coz sometimes there are many different windows with same title

Answer (score 35):

It's easy :) 
Python Popen Accept STARTUPINFO Structure...
About STARTUPINFO Structure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx

Run Hidden:

```
import subprocess

def startProgram():
    SW_HIDE = 0
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    subprocess.Popen(r'C:\test.exe', startupinfo=info)
startProgram()
```

Run Minimized:

```
import subprocess

def startProgram():
    SW_MINIMIZE = 6
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    info.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE
    subprocess.Popen(r'C:\test.exe', startupinfo=info)
startProgram()
```

Comment: I keep getting `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` error

Comment: info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose?

if you want a hidden(no window) process working in background, best way would be to write a windows service and start/stop it using usual window service mechanism. Windows service can be easily written in python e.g. here is part of my own service (it will not run without some modifications)

```
import os
import time
import traceback

import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager

import jagteraho


class JagteRahoService (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "JagteRaho"
    _svc_display_name_ = "JagteRaho (KeepAlive) Service"
    _svc_description_ = "Used for keeping important services e.g. broadband connection up"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.stop = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.log('stopping')
        self.stop = True

    def log(self, msg):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,msg))

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.log('folder %s'%os.getcwd())
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        self.start()

    def shouldStop(self):
        return self.stop

    def start(self):
        try:
            configFile = os.path.join(jagteraho.getAppFolder(), "jagteraho.cfg")
            jagteraho.start_config(configFile, self.shouldStop)
        except Exception,e:
            self.log(" stopped due to eror %s [%s]" % (e, traceback.format_exc()))
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

and you can install it by

```
python svc_jagteraho.py--startup auto install
```

and run it by

```
python python svc_jagteraho.py start
```

I will be also be seen in services list e.g. services.msc will show it and you can start/stop it else you can use commandline

```
sc stop jagteraho
```

Comment: I think this is over the top in terms of what i want. 

The purpose of the script is to run a program hidden(no window) only when you start the script. The program that i want to hide is a proprietary application that does some number crunching and is written i think in C. Python basically hides it and fetches the progress in a very nice minimalistic transparent GUI window that i written. Nothing major. The problem is that i don't want this huge window to be floating around my desktop so i want to hide it.

Comment: @wtzolt , it depends, but for long running background process service is the best way, anyway i added another solution to hide any type of window, so it should work with your app too

Comment: @wtz maybe this is a little offtopic but there is a neat little tool out there called "Power Menu" http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/ it brings some features of a major *ix desktop to windows eg. Minimize to tray or always on top

Answer (score 0):

Run Hidden:

```
from subprocess_maximize import Popen
Popen("notepad.exe",show='hidden', priority=0)
```

Before the code above, use the following command:

```
pip install subprocess-maximize
```

Comment: please add a little more info about how or why this works to improve you answer and give a little more context, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If what is appearing is a terminal, redirect the process's stdout.