# Suppress subprocess console output in a python windowed (Tkinter) app

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, pyinstaller, windows-console

I am attempting to run the following code in a python app executable made using

> pyinstaller -w -F script.py

:

```
def ffmpeg_command(sec):
    cmd1 = ['ffmpeg', '-f','gdigrab','-framerate',config.get('FFMPEG_Settings','Framerate'),'-i','desktop',gen_filename_from_timestamp_and_extension()]


    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

    duration = sec
    sleeptime = 0
    while proc.poll() is None and sleeptime < duration: 
        # Wait for the specific duration or for the process to finish
        time.sleep(1)
        sleeptime += 1

    proc.terminate()
```

The above code is run when a Tkinter button is pressed and this code is called from the button click handler.

My problem is that when I am running the exe this doesn't run ffmpeg.
However, If I set the command to be:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1)
```

FFMPEG does run, I get the movie file I wanted but I can see the console window for FFMPEG. So I end up getting the console window in my movie.
(I take care of minimizing the Tkinter window in the button click handler)

My question is how do I suppress the console window and still have FFMPEG run the way I want it to?
I looked at the following threads but couldn't make it work:
[How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess-in-python-2-7), 
[Open a program with python minimized or hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319838/open-a-program-with-python-minimized-or-hidden)

Thank you

Comment: try adding parameter **shell=True** to  proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

Comment: @Stack - Thank you for commenting. I tried modifying it to : `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL) ` But I'm still getting the same results :(

Comment: If you're using Windows 7 or older, you may have a bad stdin handle. Replace it via `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`. However, setting the handles to the `NUL` device won't prevent the allocation of a console or hide it. `shell=True` will hide it via the `STARTUPINFO`, but it's best to avoid the shell if possible and simpler to not attach to a console at all. Define `DETACHED_PROCESS = 8` and use `creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS`.

Comment: @eryksun - Changing to `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)` Makes it run like I want but now I can't terminate FFMPEG, it just keeps on screen-capturing.
However `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)` supresses the output but shows the console window. Could you please give more details on hiding the console window with `STARTUPINFO` ?

Comment: @eryksun I did further digging from your comment and STARTUPINFO indeed solved it for me. Thank you! Editing with solution

Comment: How were you terminating it before, by closing the console window? If you want to terminate the process, use `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,st‌​dout=subprocess.DEVN‌​ULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)`. Then to kill it call `proc.terminate()`.

Comment: @eryksun I used `proc.terminate()' after counting down...

Answer (score 6):

Thank you @Stack and @eryksun!
I changed to the following code:

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
cmd1 = ['ffmpeg', '-f','gdigrab','-framerate',config.get('FFMPEG_Settings','Framerate'),'-i','desktop',gen_filename_from_timestamp_and_extension()]  
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Achieved what I wanted.
Indeed, as @eryksun suggested, only redirecting the output didn't do it and I had to use `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` as well to suppress all output.

That still left the console window visible but by setting the `startupinfo` as mentioned above, the console window was hidden.
Also verified that FFMPEG goes away when the time expires.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You say that you kept `shell=True`, but you're not using it in the above code, which is for the best since this command doesn't require the shell. I still recommend telling Windows to not create a console at all via the `DETACHED_PROCESS` creation flag.