# Re-launch a software minimized

Tags: python, windows, winapi, win32gui, hwnd

I run MediaPlayerClassic, as a minimized window in the taskbar (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323367/1422096) and the other answer too), with:

```
import subprocess, win32con, win32gui, win32process, win32api

info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = win32con.SW_MINIMIZE
app = subprocess.Popen(r'c:\path\to\mpc-h64.exe "d:\mp3\song.mp3"', startupinfo=info)
```

It works. But sometimes, I would like to replace the currently-playing-song by another one, and I'm sending the same previous code (with another mp3).

Since MediaPlayerClassic allows only 1 instance, re-running the previous code does replace the currently-playing-song by the new one indeed, and this is what I want, so *it works too*. **Except that the new window is no more minimized.** This is probably because no new process is started: it reuses the previously existing process, and MediaPlayerClassic "opens the window" when it receives a new MP3 to play (?).

Adding:

```
time.sleep(0.2)  # required, if not the next action happens before the MP3 changes

def callback(hwnd, hwnds):
    text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd) == 'MediaPlayerClassicW':
        win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)
    return True

win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, [])
```

*nearly* solves it, except that the window **quickly flashes and then minimizes**.

**Question: how to relaunch a .exe already started like MediaPlayerClassic and keep it minimized?** Should something else than `subprocess.Popen` be used here?

Comment: MPC is doing this on purpose.

Comment: @Anders any idea how to avoid that MPC does this?

Comment: You should use ShellExecute() to play media files.

Comment: @Michael, no I would like to keep MPC, because I want to use MPC's user interface sometimes (by clicking it on the taskbar and open it).

Comment: Then kill the old process with TerminateProcess() and start a new one. In any case, making assumptions on a 3rd party program behaviour will create issues in future updates unless documented.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I thought about this, but I think it will introduce a bigger delay to the current solution I use (maybe 1 or 2 seconds for the app to close and restart).

Comment: using `FindWindow("WINDOWSPROJECT9",None)` instead of retrieving all windows to reduce the delay?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Thank you for your tip. The `EnumWindows` loop is in fact very short, so that's not really the problem ; if I reduce the delay too much (`time.sleep(0.2)`), the next action happens before the MP3 has changed.